# The output of GCC

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu

I have GCC running on my Ubuntu operating system. I wrote a small program in C and tried compiling it. Its output was an *a.out* file like it would do on Windows. How can I make it put out a Linux executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Linux executable. `a.out` files (actual [a.out format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out), not files named *a.out* by default) cannot be executed on Windows.

In both cases, most likely you get a standard executable usable in the local system, but named `a.out`. On Linux it's an ELF file.

Comment: So how do I execute it? When I click on it nothing happens.

Comment: On a command line, type ./a.out   Do you have a command line?  If not, create a terminal window and go to the directory where your a.out resides.

Comment: The Windows part could be left out. The OP said an "a.out" file was generated on Windows (and presumably could be executed there). The Windows part is not important for this question.

Answer (score 6):

`a.out` *is* the executable (assuming you've done full compilation rather than just generation of object files but that's the most likely case). To run it, use (from a shell):

```
./a.out
```

If you want to give it a different name, simply rename it, or better:

```
gcc -o actualname myprog.c
```

to get an executable called `actualname` which is then run (of course) with:

```
./actualname
```

See the following transcript:

```
pax> cat testprog.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) { printf("Hi.\n\n"); return 0; }

pax> gcc testprog.c ; ./a.out
Hi.

pax> gcc -o xyzzy testprog.c ; ./xyzzy
Hi.
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your C file is *f.c*.

`gcc f.c` gives the `a.out` executable, and you can run it in a terminal as `./a.out`.

`gcc f.c -o myprog` gives `myprog` as the executable, and you can run it in a terminal as `./myprog`.